# Google Sheets - Create formulas & data in Sheet 2 based on Data from Sheet 1

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets file with a wine cellar with several categories and info in Sheet 1.
I'd like to create a second sheet that uses data from sheet 1 to show statistics about the cellar.

The formula's I've got worked out and I can test by creating them in Sheet 1.

For instance, "=UNIQUE(E3:E110)" in Cell A113 gives me a list of all the countries (column E lists countries) and "=COUNTIF(E3:E110, A113)" gives me the amount of wines I have of that country.

Now I'd like to put this info in Sheet 2 but I am not able to reference the data from Sheet 1. I do know how to do it for a single cell (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) but haven't been able to create formulas with that.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a pivot table. To go further, please share a reproducible and minimal sample.